# Wall thickness for 3d print

Tags: 3d-printing, solidify-modifier

Okay guys, I need to model this jug to be resin 3d printed in smaller scales - 1:6 and 1:12.
Wall thickness should be 1.2mm for 1:6 and 1mm for 1:12.
How would you model it?
I am starting with a mesh (circle) and model the jug and for the handle I add curve (path) and add the geometry.
I am having difficulties with the wall thickness, whenever I print it, the wall is always less than 1mm thick. Thank you in advance!
[image]

Comment: Did you try the solidify modifier?

Comment: Yes, I did all test models with the solidify modifier, but I always scaled it down a bit after applying modifier and the wall turns out to be too thin.

Comment: Yup don't scale them down that changes the wall thickness

Comment: Was going to try that tomorrow